# How to save data from a one-to-one relationship in a so-call? TYPEORM and NESTJS

Tags: node.js, typescript, orm, nestjs, typeorm

I have two entities to create in the table, one for the user and the other to store the token, and when creating a user I need both to be filled in, but I don't know how to do that via the ORM of TYPEORM, how would you do a create?

UserEntity

```
@Entity('Users')
export class UserEntity {
  @ObjectIdColumn()
  _id: ObjectId;

  @Column({ type: 'string', length: 24 })
  name: string;

  @Column({ type: 'string', length: 55 })
  password: string;

  @Column({ type: 'string', length: 24 })
  email: string;

  @Column({ type: 'number', length: 24 })
  celphone: number;

  @OneToOne(() => TokenEntity, (TokenEntity) => TokenEntity.user, {
    cascade: true,
  })
  @JoinColumn()
  token: TokenEntity;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  created_at: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updated_at: Date;
}
```

TokenEntity

```
@Entity('UserTokens')
export class TokenEntity {
  @ObjectIdColumn()
  _id: ObjectId;

  @OneToOne(() => UserEntity, (user) => user.token)
  user: UserEntity;

  @Column({ type: 'string', length: '100' })
  accessToken: string;

  @Column({ type: 'number' })
  expereIn: number;
}
```

UPDATED ---

code repo

```
export class CreateUserRepo implements ICreateUserContract {
  constructor(private menagerRepo: EntityManager) {}

  public async create({
    user,
    token,
  }: ICreateUserContract.Input): Promise<void> {
    const createUserByToken = new TokenEntity();
    createUserByToken.accessToken = token.accessToken;
    createUserByToken.expereIn = token.expireIn;

    const createUser = new UserEntity();
    createUser.name = user.name;
    createUser.password = user.password;
    createUser.celphone = user.celphone;
    createUser.email = user.email;

    createUser.token = createUserByToken;

    await this.menagerRepo.save(createUser);
  }
}
```

----- Updated
it is saving in both as expected, but in the User document it is saving a Token column, with token info, but I don't want that, I want a connection only, not to save the information in the same document...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, what you want is a bi-directional relation, which is described by [typeorm](https://typeorm.io/one-to-one-relations). You attempted that with the inverse sides `(UserEntity) => UserEntity.id` and `(TokenEntity) => TokenEntity.id`. However, you want to access `UserEntity` and `TokenEntity` respectively, not their `id`. Change the accessors to `(TokenEntity) => TokenEntity.user` and `(UserEntity) => UserEntity.tokenId`, as they are declared in their classes.

Comment: I changed it, and it is saving both documents, but not the way I want, it is saving the wrong way there, I updated the code so you or someone can help me

Comment: What do you want exactly? If you want only to store `TokenEntity.id` on `UserEntity`  you need to have two attributes on `UserEntity`, e.g. `token` and `tokenId`, while `tokenId` is the actual database column in the user collection. Add `@Column()tokenId: string` and `@OneToOne(...) @JoinColumn({name: 'tokenId'})token: TokenEntity` to `UserEntity`